# Как обратиться к стилям псевдоэлемента after

Tags: javascript, jquery

При нажатие на блок, нужно изменять значения after display

Answer (score 3):

"Напрямую" никак, только при помощи других стилей.

```js
$('input').on('change', function(){
  $('.before').toggleClass('after');
});
```

```css
.before {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}

.before::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.before.after::before {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="before"></div>

<input type="checkbox" value="0">
```

---

Если нужно "отловить" клик, то есть небольшой хак:

Нужно родителю установить свойство `pointer-events: none`, а псевдоэлементу `pointer-evetns: all`, а сам обработчик клика вешать на родителя.

```js
$('.before').on('click', function(){
  console.info('click');
});
```

```css
.before {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.before::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="before"></div>
```